# Chrome showing '[Object object]' alert for plugin

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to use a specific vendor's WebRTC SDK. This vendor created a Chrome plugin for full screen sharing: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-screen-capture-ext/ckfadeloaipinhepoolddjkaaaklimcg. This plugin is quite old, from 2015, and this feature is not supported by the vendor, however it is still part of their SDK. I have some strict time limit to deliver the screenshare feature as a demo/PoC, that's why I'm trying to make this plugin work. The plugin itself actually works, however there are two issues:

When calling chrome.runtime.sendMessage, the second parameter (responseCallback) is called with empty response object, and the chrome.runtime.lastError says 'the message port closed before a response was received'. Unfortunately this is implemented in the plugin as an alert, without JSON.stringify, so it presents an alert message saying '[Object object]':

```
// The user's application sends an Event to trigger the extension to display the capture screen chooser dialog
document.addEventListener("fcsdk-capture-screen", function() {
    console.log(chrome.i18n.getMessage("msgCapturePressed"));
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: "captureScreen"}, showError);
});

function showError(response) {
    if (response == undefined) {
        alert(chrome.runtime.lastError);
    }
}
```

This I may be able to circumvent by creating the same plugin without the alert call, but it would be more preferable to get to the root cause. Unfortunately I don't have much experience with Chrome plugins, and right now not enough time to pick up the required knowledge. From what I can gather, it has something to do with a missing Promise response, but I'm not sure where. The plugin adds a listener to  chrome.runtime.onMessage, which is executed when I select what I want to share, but this happens after the alert is shown:

```
// Handle response messages from the screen chooser extension and send the response back to the user's application
// using Events
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message) {
    var messageType = message.type;

    if (messageType == "screenStreamId") {
        var streamId = message.streamId;
        console.log(chrome.i18n.getMessage("msgStreamId", [streamId]));

        var streamIdEvent = {detail: {streamId: streamId}};
        document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('fcsdk-capture-screen-stream-id', streamIdEvent));
    } else if (messageType == "userCancelled") {
        console.log(chrome.i18n.getMessage("msgCancelPressed"));
        document.dispatchEvent(new Event('fcsdk-capture-screen-cancel'));
    } else {
        console.log(chrome.i18n.getMessage("msgUnknownMessage", [messageType]));
    }
});
```

The second, more interesting issue is, when I select a screen to share, Chrome shows another alert window, but in the middle of the page instead of the top, and instead of the usual 'The page at x.x.x.x says:' title I get 'Chrome Screen Capture Extension' as title, and again '[Object object]' as message. I tried to debug it, I cannot find the source of this alert. I'm not even sure this is a normal alert. I was thinking, maybe this is the same message being alerted from Chrome itself, however after I added JSON.stringify into the showError function's alert call, the second alert is still showing the [Object object] message.

I'm at a bit of a loss here, not sure how to solve these alerts. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1) lastError is an object so the observed output is correct. You might want to use chrome.runtime.lastError.message but only in case lastError is defined, of course. 2) The onMessage listener here doesn't send anything back via sendResponse so showError makes zero sense - simply delete it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be sure to try removing the showError. But this will not fix the second issue right? With the second, "strange" alert coming from Chrome?

Comment: I tried it, the first alert is gone this way, thanks. But the second is still happening.

Comment: I found it. The same thing was happening in a background script, with 'chrome.tabs.sendMessage' function instead of 'chrome.runtime.sendMessage'. Can I assume that the responseCallback parameter is not needed here, just like in the previous case?

Comment: Yeah same since the content script also doesn't send a response via sendResponse.